# Joined Linq query to DataTable and result to DataView

Tags: c#, linq, dataview

I have two DataTables , Items and its Groups. I have a linq query to get item Name and  its Group Name by joining the 2 tables.

```
    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> dvquery = (from item in Items.AsEnumerable()
                                                            join grp in groups.AsEnumerable()
                                                              on item.Field<byte>("Group_ID") equals grp.Field<byte>("ID")
                                                              into item_grp_join
                                                              from itemgrp in item_grp_join
                                                              select new
                                                              {
                                                                  ItemName = (string)led.Field<string>("Name"),
                                                                  GName = (string)itemgrp.Field<string>("Name"),
                                                              });

            DataView dv = dvquery.AsDataView();
```

However I am getting compile time error as

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection'.  An explicity conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How to solve this error? I can easily convert the query result into a list but I need to have a dataview only , so as I can give it as datasource to grid.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Experienced the same problem, thanks for posting.

Comment: This LINQ query returs an IEnumerable and if you want it to return a EnumerableRowCollection that you can simply do .AsDataView() then you just need to do e SELECT item (the whole object not an anonymous type). Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your query returns an `IEnumerable<T>` of an anonymous type and you can't simply cast that to a `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`

I'm now sure which type of Grid you are using (e.g. from winforms? WPF? ASP? ASP MVC? etc), however I would expect that you should actually be able to pass it the IEnumerable output of the linq query if you wanted to - e.g.:

```
var query = (from item in Items.AsEnumerable()
             join grp in groups.AsEnumerable()
             on item.Field<byte>("Group_ID") equals grp.Field<byte>("ID")
             into item_grp_join
             from itemgrp in item_grp_join
             select new
             {
                ItemName = (string)led.Field<string>("Name"),
                GName = (string)itemgrp.Field<string>("Name"),
             });
grid.DataSource = query; // or possible query.ToList() as you suggest in the question!
```

If you really need to use a DataView type object, then there are blog posts about how to create these, try:

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/VIMAL.LAKHERA/LINQResultsetToDatatable06242008042629AM/LINQResultsetToDatatable.aspx
- http://www.chinhdo.com/20090402/convert-list-to-datatable/
- http://wpfguy.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to.html

Note that if you are expecting to use the grid for two-way binding (e.g. for writing changes back to the database), then this is unlikely to "just work" - as your IEnumerable projection isn't tied back to the datasource.

Comment: All the above references you mentioned first convert the query into datatable and then dataview on datatable can be set. I think then this is only option left. What if I set dataview on Datatable which was generated by Linq query ,and then somehow DataTable gets destroyed. Will the DataView work then?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an list of `anonymous` objects. It is better to create a DataTable from your query result.

```
var query = (from item in Items.AsEnumerable() .......

 DataTable view = new DataTable();
 view.Columns.Add("GroupName");
 view.Columns.Add("ItemName");
 foreach (var t in dvquery)
       {
        view.Rows.Add(t.GName, t.ItemName);
       }
 DataView dv = view.DefaultView;
```